# Porting tcsh code to bash code

Tags: bash, tcsh

I have some tcsh scripts that I need to port to bash scripts.  I did my research on the if, input/output syntax, etc but I am stuck on porting a foreach tcsh loop into a for loop and I am looking for some help.

The tcsh code looks like this:

```
set num_ids = 0
foreach x(`ls item.*.txt`)
   echo $x
   set item_id = `echo $x | cut -f2,2 -d\.`
   echo $item_id
   if ( $num_ids == 0) then
      echo $num_ids
   else
      echo "not in 0"
      echo $num_ids
   endif
   @ num_ids = $num_ids + 1
   echo "printing again $num_ids"
end # end for loop
```

How would you port that snippet into bash code?

Thanks!

Comment: Even in tcsh, the `ls` isn't necessary; the `foreach` could be `foreach x (item.*.txt)`. All `ls` is doing here is printing its arguments. (Unless one of the `item.*.txt` files is a directory.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it this way:

```
num_ids=0

for x in item.*.txt; do
    echo "$x"
    item_id=${x#item.}; item_id=${item_id%.txt}  ## same as item_id=$(echo "$x" | cut -f2,2 -d\.) but better
    echo "$item_id"
    if [[ num_ids -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo "$num_ids"
    else
        echo "not in 0"
        echo "$num_ids"
    fi
    (( ++num_ids ))  ## same as (( num_ids = num_ids + 1 ))
    echo "printing again $num_ids"
done
```

Note: `foreach x([bq]ls item.*.txt[bq])` should actually be `for x in $(ls item.*.txt)` but using `ls` is probably not necessary.

Your `if else fi` block could also be simplified as:

```
    echo "$item_id"
    [[ num_ids -ne 0 ]] && echo "not in 0"
    echo "$num_ids"
```

Comment: Hi konsolebox, thanks a lot! looks good, but this line seems odd, item_id=${x#item.}; item_id=${item_id%.txt}, isn't the # string reserved for making comments?

Comment: It's a special parameter expansion. See here: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html